# Command window closing on Enter

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm currently making a game in Windows 7 using Batch Files. So I have a sequence where it asks you a question and you type in the answer:

```
:MainMenu
set /p LMainMenu=
if %LMainMenu%==1 goto PlayMenu
if %LMainMenu%==2 goto ColourMenu
if %LMainMenu%==3 goto Reset1
if %LMainMenu%==4 goto AboutMenu
goto MainMenu
```

So if someone doesn't type anything in and presses 'Enter', the CMD window will close. How do I prevent this from happening? I added the 'goto MainMenu' so if they type in anything other than 1,2,3,4, they will be taken back. 
Much will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You should handle empty string as one of the answers

Comment: I tried adding:
if %LMainMenu%== goto MainMenu
It still closes if I press Enter.

Comment: That's a syntax error for empty strings. Surround the values with quotes: `IF "%LMainMenu%=="" GOTO MainMenu`

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
:MainMenu
set /a LMainMenu=1
set /p "LMainMenu=enter a number: "
```

For more help see `help set` on the command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a default selection (automatically selected when the user just presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>), use the solution [Endoro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17541554/1630171) suggested. If you want to loop until the user makes a valid selection, use this instead:

```
:MainMenu
set "LMainMenu="
set /p "LMainMenu=Enter a number [1-4]: "
if not defined LMainMenu goto MainMenu
if "%LMainMenu%"=="1" goto PlayMenu
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this should work.
if "%LMainMenu%"=="" goto MainMenu

Comment: That can't possibly work. The variable remains undefined when the user just presses [Enter] at the prompt, so `%LMainMenu%` produces the literal string "%LMainMenu%". It's not expanded to an empty string.